# Firefox: double-click on titlebar maximize window instead on open new tab

Tags: firefox

Recently, I noted that Firefox started to behave differently when I double-click on its title-bar / tab-bar.

It maximizes the windows as if I clicked on the semaphore <kbd>+</kbd> button, instead of opening a new tab like it used to do before.

Anyone knows how to get the old behavior back?

Answer (score 1):

Double-click to maximise is a System pref

 menu > System Preferences > Dock

Uncheck "Double-click a window's title bar to…zoom"

[image]

Comment: Actually I'm still on Yosemite cause of compatibility issues, and there is no option to zoom, only minimize. Anyway it always have been unchecked since I have my Mac.

Comment: ah, OK - must be new Firefox behaviour itself then. I've not used it myself, so all I could suggest is dig & see if you can find a pref

Comment: Yes, it seems that, on older OSX, if "Double-click to minimize" is unchecked, it behaves as if El Capitan's "Double-click to maximize" was selected. Anyway, I searched in all preference panes, also in the about:config advanced page, but found nothing.